# pacman warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!

Tags: arch-linux, upgrade, pacman, artix-linux

In the past few weeks, I have not been able to update my Linux system (Artix/Arch).

This is what happens:

```
~ sudo pacman -Syu     
:: Synchronizing package databases...
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
...
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
warning: running XferCommand: fork failed!
error: failed to synchronize all databases (error invoking external downloader)
```

Same result using `-Syyu`.

In the past this command always worked. My internet connection is fine (I tried both with Wi-Fi and wired, `ping` is successful). My mirrorlist file is up to date.

I have not been able to find any information related to these error messages.

Thank you for any help.

---

Current configuration:

Kernel: 5.17.8-artix1-1

---

More info:

```
grep XferCommand /etc/pacman.conf
#XferCommand = /usr/bin/curl -L -C - -f -o %o %u
XferCommand = /usr/bin/wget --passive-ftp -c -O %o %u
```

Comment: What does `grep XferCommand /etc/pacman.conf`return? Add to your question, please.

Comment: @ajgringo619 - I added the details you asked for. Thank you.

Comment: @ajgringo619 - Swapping the comment among the two lines I get from grep, `pacman` behaves as expected. If you want to write it as an answer, I will accept it. Thnx

Comment: Interesting...on my EndeavourOS system, both of these commands are commented out (not sure what the default is). There's really nothing for me to answer - I didn't do anything.